# Why I get different results when using jQuery and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

This is my html code

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <tbody>
        <tr class="data">
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="data">
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="data">
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="data">
            <td>4</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="data">
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="data">
            <td>6</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="data">
            <td>7</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

and I use jQuery datatables with script of jQuery

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "lengthMenu": [[5, 25, 50, -1], [5, 25, 50, "All"]],
    "columnDefs": [
            { type: "num", targets: 0 },
     ]
});
```

And I don't understand why I use this code below it display 2 different results

```
list= document.getElementsByClassName("data");
console.log(list.length); // 7
$('button').on('click', function() {
    console.log(list.length); //5
});
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first `console.log(list.length);` would have been executed before `$('#example').DataTable` and it will return `7` as there are `7` rows with class `data`.

That is because once you have applied with `$('#example').DataTable` it will only render (display) `5 rows`, so when you use `list.length` it will return `5`.

---

**FYI** - `Document.getElementsByClassName()` will not `cache` result into `list` object when you write `list = document.getElementsByClassName("data");`. It means when you use `list.length` inside `click` it will perform `document.getElementsByClassName("data").length`. Each time you use `list` it will scan entire document again and again.

Reference - [Document.getElementsByClassName()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName)

> Warning: This is a live [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). Changes in the DOM will reflect in the array as the changes occur. If an element selected by this array no longer qualifies for the selector, it will automatically be removed. Be aware of this for iteration purposes.

Comment: The first value in the lengthMenu is used for the default pageLength.  So 5 it is.  Nice catch Karan!